# how to disable vim's notification temporary

Tags: vim

I have a vim script will change something in the buffer before save.

But this script will trigger VIM to print a notification like below.

```
"file.txt" 112L, 4391C written
1 change; before #46  0 seconds ago
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

How can I stop it?

Here the scripts :

-- script.lua

```
function update()
  local b = vim.buffer()
  for i = 1, 10 do
    local line = b[i]
    if line and line:match('updated_on:.*') then
      b[i] = line:gsub('updated_on:.*', 'updated_on: '..os.date())
      break
    end
  end
end
function undo()
  vim.command'call UndoIt()'
end
vim.command"autocmd BufWritePre * lua update()"
vim.command"autocmd BufWritePost * lua undo()"
```

-- script.vim

```
function! UndoIt()
  let l:winview = winsaveview()
  undo
  call winrestview(l:winview)
endfunction
```

Comment: You could start by showing us the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the script, find out where the write is being done, and add `silent` before that command.
For example, if the write is being done through the `write` command, replace `write` with `silent write`.

See `:h :silent` for details.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I added my scripts above. You can see I'm not call write myself. I just change the buffer before save and undo it back after save. So where should I put the silent ?

Comment: just tried~ it's work~ I just added silent before the lua call like `vim.command"autocmd BufWritePre * silent lua update()"`